# Halting problem - What if the halting algorithm gave more than one output?

Tags: turing-machines, computability

Sorry I don't know how silly a question this might be, but i've been reading up on the halting problem lately, and understand the halting problem cannot possibly output a value that is "correct" when fed a machine that does the opposite of itself. This therefore proves the halting problem cannot be solved by contradiction.

What if you were to give the halting algorithm 3 possible outputs, something like:

- Yes
- No
- Non-deterministic (for paradox's like this one)

You could argue then that for a non-deterministic output it would then do something entirely different, but this would be okay because it is still non-deterministic behavior. For a simple algorithm input, such as a `while True: pass` it would be incorrect to output non-determinism, since it will always be No.

I was wondering if this would change its solve-ability, or would it still be un-solvable?

Thanks for any responses

Comment: Your problem isn't well-defined at the moment. You have to explain when the algorithm should return Yes, when it should return No, and when the third option.

Comment: It would return yes and no in precisely the same cases as before, except in the case there is some recursive-like paradox, so gives the 3rd option since there is no defined solution.

Comment: What does "recursive-like paradox" mean? You have to give a precise definition. For me, a Turing machine either halts or not. I don't see any third option. It's like asking whether $a=b+c$: it's either true or false. No third option.

Comment: Well consider the proof for proving it is impossible to determine something halts, given a program and an input. A machine can be constructed that takes the output (Yes/No) of the halting algorithm, and feeds that into the next stage doing the opposite of what the halting program output. Therefore can never possibly given the correct output (non-deterministic). Being a contradiction, the algorithm cannot exist. I'm asking what happens if the halting algorithm were to notice this, and realise the paradox of doing the opposite of what it outputs, therefore return an output of "non-deterministic"

Comment: You haven't answered the question. I'm giving you a Turing machine $T$. When is the answer Yes? When is it No? When is it the third option?

Comment: when the machine is deterministic, it will return Yes and No for precisely the same cases as before. When the machine is non-deterministic, like above it says that. Could even say the same for a program that generates a random number and halts if the number is 1, and doesn't halt if 2

Comment: The machines considered in the halting problem are all deterministic. The input to the halting problem is a deterministic Turing machine, and the output is Yes if the machine halts, and No if it doesn't halt.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107942/discussion-between-nightshade-and-yuval-filmus).

Answer (score 1):

*It doesn't matter if and when some newly defined machine $M$ outputs an extra value - the original machine $H$ of the halting problem still leads to a contradiction.*

---

The proof of the halting problem relies on showing that if we assume there is an oracle machine $Q$ solving the halting problem that we can construct a machine $H$ that uses $Q$ such that a logical contradiction results, proving that $H$ cannot be constructed. But if $H$ cannot be constructed then either the act of constructing $H$ from $Q$ is impossible (i.e. mathematics as a whole is inconsistent and we can just go home) or $Q$ is impossible.

Of course you can imagine you can construct another machine $M$ from $Q$ which gives an answer that is not contradictory - the simplest such machine is $M=Q$. However, this is completely irrelevant: for proof by contradiction it is enough that it is possible to construct a single contradiction because once there is even a single contradiction it all collapses. Therefore it does not matter how many non-contradictory examples you construct - they do not make the contradiction go away.

This is because in mathematics you cannot "replace" anything like you could replace a flat tire: the halting problem uses a machine $H$ to construct a contradiction. If you now use a machine $M$ that causes no contradiction then it no longer is the "**h**alting problem" but the "**m**alting problem" - something completely different. Therefore no matter what you do, the solvability of the halting problem does never change.

So yes, you can construct your new machine $M$ such that it doesn't lead to a contradiction - but it doesn't change the solvability of $H$.

---

So it doesn't even matter how you construct $M$. But let's consider it anyway.

- If there exists $F$ such that $Q=F^{-1}\circ M$ (and thus $M=F\circ Q$) on a sufficiently large domain (necessarily countably infinite, but that's not sufficient) then $M$ is an oracle machine like $Q$, so it can be input to the halting problem and still lead to a contradiction.
- If such an $F$ doesn't exist then $M$ does not fulfill the premise of the halting problem because $M$ is no oracle machine. Then the halting problem does not apply to $M$ - but that does not mean that the halting problem is "solved" - it simply doesn't apply in this case.

The reason why other commentators are asking for your precise definition of $M$ is because depending on that definition it falls into one or the other case and they don't know which one.

But as per the above considerations that is irrelevant.

---

> Say you do construct $M$ from $F$ and $Q$, how do you then construct $H$ that results in a contradiction on the new oracle machine?

The construction is simple: if $H=G\circ Q$ then $H'=G\circ Q'$ where $Q'=F^*\circ M$ where $F^*$ could be defined e.g. as $F^*(\textrm{"maybe"})=\textrm{"no"}$ (several other constructions are possible: one could renumber the indices, asking for the $n$th value that doesn't provide "maybe", just like we can ask for the $n$th prime number - either way, the "maybe" can be eliminated).

**But the critical question is: is $M$ (and therefore $Q'$) still an oracle?**

If $M$ is no longer an oracle then the halting problem does not apply. And if it is an oracle the halting problem still leads to a contradiction.

The halting problem asks for a an oracle $Q$ which can determine for **all** functions whether they halt.

That is, the function is supposed to be total, producing always 0 "yes" or 1 "no" but never $\bot$ (not halting).

Your machine $M$ is equivalent to taking a "partial oracle" $P$ that is partial, ocasionally producing $\bot$ and declaring that $M$ knows when $P$ would produce $\bot$ and return "maybe" instead.

Conversely, for your machine $M$ we can construct $P$ by having it do an endless loop whenever it encounters "maybe".

Some such provers $P$ (and associated $M$) can be constructed. For example:

- if there exists $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $M(k)=\textrm{"maybe"}$ for all $k>m$ then it's no oracle (or a rather poor one) because it decides only finitely many cases.
- But even if it decides infinitely many cases it still might be no oracle: let's say $M(2\cdot k)=\textrm{"maybe"}$ for all $k>m$ so it ignores only the even ones - but the functions associated to the odd numbers could all be defined as $F_{2\cdot k+1}(n)=n+k$ which trivially halts.

To them the halting problem does not apply because they do not promise computing all functions.

---

Ultimately, it comes down that we can compute only functions which we can describe by a finite program, so we can give them a number $n\in\mathbb{N}$ to identify them.

However, the functions go $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$. There exist $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}=\mathbb{R}$ such functions, but the computable functions can address only $\mathbb{N}$ of them.

The halting problem is asking about whether we can identify the subset of $\mathbb{N}$ representing functions that terminate - and answers in the negative, stating that an oracle being capable of deciding this cannot be represented by a finite number, i.e. needing an infinitely large program.

1. So if you have infinitely many memory and time you could construct an oracle that can decide whether an arbitrary program terminates or not.
2. In practice one can only construct a "partial oracle" that can be represented by a finite number. The halting problem doesn't apply - but it also can decide only a limited (albeit infinite) number of functions.
3. What remains are partial oracles that cannot decide everything (hence the halting problem doesn't apply) yet still need an infinite description - which is the worst of both worlds.

Comment: This is interesting and potentially answers lots. Say you do construct M from F and Q, how do you then construct H that results in a contradiction on the new oracle machine?

Comment: Added that, and some discussion on oracles - but it's up to you to actually define $M$ - and I'm done with this question.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we allow an algorithm to return "Yes, it halts", "No, it doesn't halt", or "I don't know".  Then the proof no longer applies; and in fact this modified version of the halting problem is decidable.  For instance, a very simple algorithm could always output "I don't know", and it'd never be wrong.  Unfortunately, that very simple algorithm probably isn't very useful.

If this is what you meant by "non-determinism", then it is possible but not useful.